# How to trigger capture button of native camera programatically in android

Tags: android-camera

I am trying to develop a remote trigger for `native camera` app. I am searching for this in Google but didn't find any way. I don't want to open `camera intent` but trigger the `capture button` of native camera app like `wireless selfie stick`.